# How to place two smaller buttons beneath a bigger button - html, css

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have been trying to make a website from scratch using the django framework in Python. I am trying to make a split screen landing page and on each side, I want three buttons: Read More, Sign up, Log in.

I want the "sign up" button and "log in" button to be underneath the bigger "read more" button, but I have been unsuccessful for many hours. I am very much a beginner in web development so please forgive me for any silly errors.

Code for buttons "Read more" and "Sign up"(so far):

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
  width: 15rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: #fff solid 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split left d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1> The Business </h1>
    <a href="#" class="button"> Read More </a>
    <div class="Buttons">
      <div class="SignUp">
        <a href="#" class="button"> Sign up </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split right d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1> The Artist </h1>
    <a href="#" class="button"> Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the way the sign up and read more buttons are currently showing on one side of my split screen (I have not done the other side yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ixFl.jpg)

EDIT: [This is the way I want my buttons to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Xy1.png)

Comment: one thing I spot right away is this line: `.button {position: relative; left: 50%; top: 40%;}`. If you use coordinates placements, you should have `position: fixed;`, `position: absolute;` or `position: sticky;`

Comment: can you make a drawing please how you want the buttons to be exact with the placement? Makes it easier to understand what you trying to do and how you could do it most efficiently.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for the reply! Just added the drawing, I hope that helps. Also I had the position as absolute before, and I was just trying different things. When I had it as absolute, both the buttons would be overlapping on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I edited a bit on your CSS for the buttons and your HTML structure for `<div class="Buttons">`. That way all 3 buttons are inside the same wrapper and will be displayed like your image suggest.

I changed the `block` type to `inline-block`. Certainly there are other ways, but this works without to much switching on your code.
I also deleted your positioning and transform as they are not needed.

Next I swapped your link class buttons to an unique class name for the different buttons. I adress the styling through its parent and use the class name to style the width.
Last but not least, I added margins to get some spacings between the buttons.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.Buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.Buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border: black solid 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.readMore {
  width: 30rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.signUp,
.logIn {
  width: calc(15rem - 10px);
}

.signUp {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split left d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1> The Business </h1>
    <div class="Buttons">
      <a href="#" class="readMore">Read More</a>
      <a href="#" class="signUp">Sign up</a>
      <a href="#" class="logIn">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split right d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1> The Artist </h1>
    <div class="Buttons">
      <a href="#" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need all that positions. The only thing you need is sizes of the buttons. The `Read More` button should be given a bigger size and the other buttons should be given smaller sizes. Then you can apply `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to place the buttons in center.

Comment: The problem I am having when I remove the position of the button is that, for some reason, the buttons are getting pulled to the top left corner. However, they do stack underneath as I want them to. I'm going to try what you said about the margins.

Comment: @Dhritiman Thamuli Saikia, welcome to SO. Please take your time to read the SO guidlines. Your anwser lack of a specific solution or better yet a code snippet to verify. It is very vague. As such it should only be used as comment.

Comment: @tacoshy, thank you. I will keep in mind before answering

Comment: @SatyenSingh, apply `margin-top`, `margin-left` and `margin-right` to the buttons.